# SQLite combine SELECT EXISTS and CASE

Tags: sqlite

I would like to do something like this with SQLite:

```
CASE (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Tab_SB1_Bordi WHERE nome='P7BOA04022.68R'))
    WHEN  1 THEN UPDATE Tab_SB1_Bordi SET Altezza=55 WHERE nome='P7BOA04022.68R';
END
```

the syntaxs looks fine but I got an error concerning the CASE statement, any hints?

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine just running the isolated update:

```
UPDATE Tab_SB1_Bordi SET Altezza = 55 WHERE nome = 'P7BOA04022.68R';
```

This already gives you the behavior you want.  If no such matching records exist, then nothing happens, otherwise the update takes place.

Comment: Correct, and if the user gets back a zero records updated, you know you need to insert.